# Condition for "COPYRIGHT AND CONSENT FORM"

Tags: publications, copyright

I have a conference paper which is indexed by IEEE by a copyring with the following terms. My paper is an extented abstract without any proofs and details. Now I want to submit the same paper with all proofs and details to a journal. Can I do it

> IEEE COPYRIGHT AND CONSENT FORM 
>   To ensure uniformity of treatment among all contributors, other forms may not be substituted for this form, nor may any wording
>   of the form be changed. This form is intended for original material submitted to the IEEE and must accompany any such material
>   in order to be published by the IEEE. Please read the form carefully and keep a copy for your files.
>
> Paper NAME
>   Author's NAMES
>   Proceedings of 6th Iranian joint congress on Fuzzy and Intelligent Systems
>   COPYRIGHT TRANSFER
>   The undersigned hereby assigns to The Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers, Incorporated (the "IEEE") all rights
>   under copyright that may exist in and to: (a) the Work, including any revised or expanded derivative works submitted to the IEEE
>   by the undersigned based on the Work; and (b) any associated written or multimedia components or other enhancements
>   accompanying the Work.
>
> GENERAL TERMS
>
> The undersigned represents that he/she has the power and authority to make and execute this form.
>   The undersigned agrees to indemnify and hold harmless the IEEE from any damage or expense that may arise in the
>   event of a breach of any of the warranties set forth above.
>   The undersigned agrees that publication with IEEE is subject to the policies and procedures of the IEEE PSPB
>   Operations Manual.
>   In the event the above work is not accepted and published by the IEEE or is withdrawn by the author(s) before
>   acceptance by the IEEE, the foregoing copyright transfer shall be null and void. In this case, IEEE will retain a copy of
>   the manuscript for internal administrative/record-keeping purposes.
>   For jointly authored Works, all joint authors should sign, or one of the authors should sign as authorized agent for the
>   others.
>   The author hereby warrants that the Work and Presentation (collectively, the "Materials") are original and that he/she is
>   the author of the Materials. To the extent the Materials incorporate text passages, figures, data or other material from the
>   works of others, the author has obtained any necessary permissions. Where necessary, the author has obtained all third
>   party permissions and consents to grant the license above and has provided copies of such permissions and consents
>   to IEEE
>
> CONSENT AND RELEASE
>
> ln the event the author makes a presentation based upon the Work at a conference hosted or sponsored in whole or in
>   part by the IEEE, the author, in consideration for his/her participation in the conference, hereby grants the IEEE the
>   unlimited, worldwide, irrevocable permission to use, distribute, publish, license, exhibit, record, digitize, broadcast,
>   reproduce and archive, in any format or medium, whether now known or hereafter developed: (a) his/her presentation
>   and comments at the conference; (b) any written materials or multimedia files used in connection with his/her
>   presentation; and (c) any recorded interviews of him/her (collectively, the "Presentation"). The permission granted
>   includes the transcription and reproduction of the Presentation for inclusion in products sold or distributed by IEEE and
>   live or recorded broadcast of the Presentation during or after the conference.
>   In connection with the permission granted in Section 1, the author hereby grants IEEE the unlimited, worldwide,
>   irrevocable right to use his/her name, picture, likeness, voice and biographical information as part of the advertisement,
>   distribution and sale of products incorporating the Work or Presentation, and releases IEEE from any claim based on
>   right of privacy or publicity.
>
> BY TYPING IN YOUR FULL NAME BELOW AND CLICKING THE SUBMIT BUTTON, YOU CERTIFY THAT SUCH ACTION
>   CONSTITUTES YOUR ELECTRONIC SIGNATURE TO THIS FORM IN ACCORDANCE WITH UNITED STATES LAW, WHICH
>   AUTHORIZES ELECTRONIC SIGNATURE BY AUTHENTICATED REQUEST FROM A USER OVER THE INTERNET AS A
>   VALID SUBSTITUTE FOR A WRITTEN SIGNATURE.
>
> Information for Authors
>
> AUTHOR RESPONSIBILITIES
>
> The IEEE distributes its technical publications throughout the world and wants to ensure that the material submitted to its
>   publications is properly available to the readership of those publications. Authors must ensure that their Work meets the
>   requirements as stated in section 8.2.1 of the IEEE PSPB Operations Manual, including provisions covering originality,
>   authorship, author responsibilities and author misconduct. More information on IEEE’s publishing policies may be found at 
>   http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/rights/authorrightsresponsibilities.html Authors are advised especially of
>   IEEE PSPB Operations Manual section 8.2.1.B12: "It is the responsibility of the authors, not the IEEE, to determine whether
>   disclosure of their material requires the prior consent of other parties and, if so, to obtain it." Authors are also advised of IEEE
>   PSPB Operations Manual section 8.1.1B: "Statements and opinions given in work published by the IEEE are the expression of
>   the authors."
>
> RETAINED RIGHTS/TERMS AND CONDITIONS
>   Authors/employers retain all proprietary rights in any process, procedure, or article of manufacture described in the Work.
>   Authors/employers may reproduce or authorize others to reproduce the Work, material extracted verbatim from the Work, or
>   derivative works for the author's personal use or for company use, provided that the source and the IEEE copyright notice are
>   indicated, the copies are not used in any way that implies IEEE endorsement of a product or service of any employer, and the
>   copies themselves are not offered for sale.
>   Although authors are permitted to re-use all or portions of the Work in other works, this does not include granting third-party
>   requests for reprinting, republishing, or other types of re-use.The IEEE Intellectual Property Rights office must handle all such
>   third-party requests.
>   Authors whose work was performed under a grant from a government funding agency are free to fulfill any deposit mandates
>   from that funding agency.
>
> AUTHOR ONLINE USE
>   Personal Servers. Authors and/or their employers shall have the right to post the accepted version of IEEE-copyrighted
>   articles on their own personal servers or the servers of their institutions or employers without permission from IEEE, provided
>   that the posted version includes a prominently displayed IEEE copyright notice and, when published, a full citation to the
>   original IEEE publication, including a link to the article abstract in IEEE Xplore. Authors shall not post the final, published
>   versions of their papers.
>   Classroom or Internal Training Use. An author is expressly permitted to post any portion of the accepted version of his/her
>   own IEEE-copyrighted articles on the author's personal web site or the servers of the author's institution or company in
>   connection with the author's teaching, training, or work responsibilities, provided that the appropriate copyright, credit, and
>   reuse notices appear prominently with the posted material. Examples of permitted uses are lecture materials, course packs, e-
>   reserves, conference presentations, or in-house training courses.
>   Electronic Preprints. Before submitting an article to an IEEE publication, authors frequently post their manuscripts to their
>   own web site, their employer's site, or to another server that invites constructive comment from colleagues. Upon submission
>   of an article to IEEE, an author is required to transfer copyright in the article to IEEE, and the author must update any
>   previously posted version of the article with a prominently displayed IEEE copyright notice. Upon publication of an article by
>   the IEEE, the author must replace any previously posted electronic versions of the article with either (1) the full citation to the IEEE work with a Digital Object Identifier (DOI) or link to the article abstract in IEEE Xplore, or (2) the accepted version only
>   (not the IEEE-published version), including the IEEE copyright notice and full citation, with a link to the final, published article
>   in IEEE Xplore.
>
> Questions about the submission of the form or manuscript must be sent to the publication's editor. 
>   Please direct all questions about IEEE copyright policy to: 
>   IEEE Intellectual Property Rights Office, copyrights@ieee.org, +1-732-562-3966

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to write to IEEE (they have an email address at the end), but I do not think you can republish this work, based on this part:

> **Although authors are permitted to re-use all or portions of the Work in other works, this does not include granting third-party requests
>   for reprinting, republishing, or other types of re-use.**

Answer (score 2):

Normally the same paper cannot be published twice. To give the paper and yourself more visibility, your options are: (1) present it in a workshop without proceedings; (2) prepare an extended version that has additional content and publish that in a journal.

Comment: My paper in the above conference is an extented abstract  Without any proofs and details. Now I want to submit the same paper with all proofs and details. Can I do it?

Comment: @vector I think, yes. When filled with details, proofs, examples, extra experimental results, etc, it stops being the same paper.